# How to make atom detect .jade correctly?

Tags: html, pug, atom-editor

I want to see jade highlighting when I open .jade file on mac. 
Currently I have https://atom.io/packages/language-jade installed, but when I open .jade file atom detect it as html. 
I install https://atom.io/packages/file-types and add to config file (atom->open your config):

```
"file-types":
    jade: «source.jade»
```

It don't change anything at all.
I think default atom language-html plugin override my settings. 
If I disable language-html, then atom detect .jade correctly and highlight it properly. 
But without language-html plugin atom detect html as plain text and don't highlight it at all.
What I should to to get both html and jade proper highlighting?

With all best regards. Anton.

Comment: it should be by deafult. probably it worths filing issue for this repo https://github.com/devongovett/atom-jade/issues

Comment:  stupid-comment-size-stackoverflow-limit